# draw lines consisting of images

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+, gdi

I would like to use GDI+ and C# to be able to draw lines consisting of images in WinForms.Please note that It is not to draw simple lines over an image but to draw lines made up of images like ***********************************(each * is a specific image).

For example, i have an imageA, and the line will be like imageAimageAimageAimageAimageAimageAimageAimageAimageAimageAimageAimageAimageAimageAimageAimageA

Do you have an example or some advice?

Answer (score 1):

Create [Pen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.pen.aspx) by using [TextureBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.texturebrush.aspx) as parameter and then use Pen in [Graphics.DrawLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawLine.aspx) method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Graphics.DrawImage` method. You need to pass your `Image ImageA` as first parameter and a `Point`, the point in your form where you want your ImageA to be located.
If you follow this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you will find the usage of this method and its other overrides.
Hope this helps! ^^